# how to get done in button like in favorites tab of iphone phone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

how can i get done button like in favorites tab of native phone app which appears after we click edit button in favorites tab .

i though they were two barbutton items , hiding according to need ,but when i tried to place new barbutton item on my  old one , old one replacing and new one only existing :S

thanks in advance

regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a <del>`UITableViewController`</del> `UIViewController` subclass, this is provided for you as the `editButtonItem` property. You can set either bar button item of your navigation bar to that and you will get the behavior out of the box.

```
[self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:self.editButtonItem];
```

You may need to provide a `setEditing:animated:` implementation to transition your views to and from the editing state if you're not using a `UITableViewController`.

Comment: thanks for help , i tried this code in my viewDidload method but its not showing any button ? :S  P.S : I am using tabbar controller

Comment: Your tab bar controller needs to contain a navigation controller, which then contains your view controller.